# Cannot insert into table. PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named 'Directors' in the database 'db2'.
I have an HTML form. I would like when I insert the values and hit submit button, to insert the content into the table in a new row (to INSERT INTO), after it makes some validations (you'll notice them in the script). I've tried to do it by myself, but it is always echoing me 'Fail';
This is my HTML form:

```
    <form action="process.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="pages_edit_nonce" />        

            <div class="section-item page-title-section">
                <label for="title">Full Name:</label><span class="help">*</span><div class="input-wrap"><input type="text" name="name" value=""  /></div>        </div>



    <div class="section-item">
        <label for="label">Phone:</label><span class="help">*Optionally</span><div class="input-wrap"><input type="text" name="phone" value=""  /></div>        </div>

    <div class="section-item">
        <label for="redirect">Е-mail:</label><span class="help">*</span><div class="input-wrap"><input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder=""  /></div>        </div>

    <div class="section-item">
        <label for="redirect">School:</label><span class="help">*</span><div class="input-wrap"><input type="text" name="school" value="" placeholder=""  /></div>        </div>

    <div class="section-item">
        <label for="redirect">City:</label><span class="help">*</span><div class="input-wrap"><input type="text" name="city" value="" placeholder=""  /></div>        </div>

    <div class="section-item">
        <label for="redirect">Password:</label><span class="help">*</span><div class="input-wrap"><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder=""  /></div>        </div>

    <div class="admin-bar">
        <div class="admin-bar-inner">


            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

This is my process.php file:

```
$server = "localhost";
    $user = "****";
    $pass = "****";

    $conn = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
    $db = mysql_select_db("****", $conn);
    session_start();
    if(!$db) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = "<strong>Error:</strong> The access to the database is denied!";
        header("Location: ../../admin/error/");
        exit();
    }

    session_start();

    function UniqueID() {
        $UID = rand(); //Create unique ID
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Directors` WHERE `UID` = '$UID'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($check) > 0) { //Check if it exists
            UniqueID(); //Redo the function
        } else {
            return $UID; //return the uniqueid
        }
    }

    $UID = UniqueID(); //Unique ID
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $password = $_POST['password']; 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $city = $_POST['city']; 

    //Create INSERT query
    $qry = "INSERT INTO `oclass`.`Directors`(`UID`,`Name`, `Phone`, `Email`, `SchoolGymnasium`, `City`, `Password`) VALUES('$UID','$name','$phone','$email','$school','$city','" . md5($password) . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        $_SESSION['SUCCMSGADDDIR'] = 'Sucessful.';
        header("location: URL");
        exit();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSGADDDIR'] = 'Fail';
        header("location: URL");
    }
```

After changing the error session with mysql_error() it gave me the following error:
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in ... on line 10;
Line 10 is:

```
mysql_error() = "<strong>Error:</strong> The access to the database is denied!";
```

I've removed the column named ID (which was Primary Key) and set UID column as Primary Key, and now is working. Thank you guys.

Comment: If you're getting "Fail" all the time it means that the condition if($result) is returning false, which means that $result is not a valid resource in this case caused by a bad query ( mysql error ). Echo mysql_error and see what you're getting.

Comment: Consider using `PDO` or `mysqli` and not `mysql_*`.
Anyway , in order to debug the query , change the value of the failed session to: `mysql_error()` and share the output.

Comment: to change $_SESSION['SUCCMSGADDDIR'] with mysql_error() ?

Comment: or you can just echo the error echo mysql_error() and remove the header() for the time being

Comment: I've done it. I've updated the answer with the echo mysql_error() result.

Comment: please use some mysql_real_escape_string on your variables before using them in your queries

Comment: problem connecting to database!! are you sure of the user name and password?

Comment: Yes, they are correct. I've just copied them from the script and connected successfully.

Comment: Err, you are trying to assign a message to the mysql_error() function. You just need to echo out mysql_error() and see what it says.

Comment: why did you write $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = "<strong>Error:</strong> The access to the database is denied!";
just S_SESSION['errmsg']=mysql_error();
even only echo mysql_error() will do but u need to comment out the header

Comment: Oh... sorry. This is what it is saying: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'. I have a Column named ID, which I do not insert. Can that be a problem?

Comment: if uid is your primary key then either remove PI from uid column(i mean donot use the UID as primary key), or remove the UID in the insert statement

Comment: Make UID an auto increment column, then you do not need it in the insert statement (or if you still want to specify it then just insert NULL as that fields value in the INSERT statement

Comment: I've removed the column named ID (which was Primary Key) and set UID column as Primary Key, and now is working. Thank you guys.

Comment: you have to set your value of the column "id" to autoincrement or it will be by default 0 everytime - makes more sense to have some primary key "id" and not "uid" there may be even some collissions using uid, so please also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php but rand() can have much more collissions. also please use sha256 or better instead of md5

Comment: You try to assign a String to a funktion, mysql_error() = "bla" would not work.

Comment: Your `UniqueID()` function does not always return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must have never heard of SQL injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.  Your current code is opening you up for attacks. You can't directly insert user input into the database like you're doing. Also mysql_* functions are deprecated. To help your code be safer and more update try something like this:

```
session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$user = "****";
$pass = "****";
$db   = "****";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);  
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `oclass`.`Directors`(`UID`,`Name`, `Phone`, `Email`, `SchoolGymnasium`, `City`, `Password`) VALUES (:uid, :name, :phone, :email, :school, :city, :password)");

$stmt->bindParam(':uid',      uniqid());
$stmt->bindParam(':name',     $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':phone',    $_POST['phone']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email',    $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':school',   $_POST['school']);
$stmt->bindParam(':city',     $_POST['city']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', md5($_POST['password']));

$stmt->execute();
```